# syntax error, unexpected 'FIND_IN_SET' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using FIND_IN_SET in where condition in Codeigniter, and I am facing the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'FIND_IN_SET' (T_STRING)
```

How to solve it??

My model is the following:

```
function getTask($id, $is_master_admin) 
{
    $this->db->select('task.*, workspace.title as workspacetitle, GROUP_CONCAT(user.title ) AS usertitle,task.assigneduserid,user,id',FALSE);
    $this->db->join(WORKSPACE , WORKSPACE . '.id = ' . TASK . '.workspaceid', 'inner');
    $this->db->join(USER,USER . '.id = ' . TASK . '.assigneduserid', 'inner');
    $this->db->from(TASK);
    $this->db->group_by("task.id");         
    if (!$is_master_admin) {
        $this->db->where FIND_IN_SET($id,"task.assigneduserid");
    }

    $this->db->where(TASK . '.tasktypeid', '1');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this, thank you.

Comment: @MikeB so what if i am asking question about syntax error

Comment: You have syntaxt error on this line : `$this->db->where FIND_IN_SET($id,"task.assigneduserid");`

Comment: @Ritesh http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87149/should-syntax-error-questions-be-closed-as-too-localized-after-being-answered - Syntax errors are either so unique that they're unlikely to help anyone in the future (the primary mandate of this site is to help others, not yourself) or they're too trivial. In this case it's a syntax error that doesn't even resemble valid PHP code. A simple review of a codeigniter db tutorial or basic php syntax would have resolved this. You even have a valid `where()` call right below it for reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->where FIND_IN_SET($id,"task.assigneduserid");
```

to

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET($id, task.assigneduserid)");
```

you forgot to open paranthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use find_in_set as below

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$id',task.assigneduserid) !=", 0);
```